# route components inside a component in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

i have a login page which contains 3 roles to login. Admin, student and company so instead of changing the whole page i just want to change the login component of the respective role.

> login page

```
export default function Authpage(){


    return(
        <div className="authpagemain">
            <div className="authsection">
                <div className="logo">
                    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxi9wcchp/image/upload/v1661091025/quantum_olddxf.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-route">
                    <Studentlogin />
                    <span>
                <Link
                href="/">Admin</Link>
                <Link href="/">Student</Link>
                <Link href="/">Company</Link>
            </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

> student login component

```
export function Studentlogin(){
    const [stemail, setStemail] = useState(String);
    const [stpassword, setStpassword] = useState(String);

    async function Login(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const student = await pb.collection('users').authWithPassword(stemail, stpassword);
        console.log(student)
    }
    return(
        <form className="login-form">
            <h3>Student Login</h3>
            <input 
            className="login-email" 
            type="email" 
            placeholder="Enter Student Email" 
            onChange={(e)=> setStemail(e.target.value)}/>
            <input
            className="login-password"
            type="password" 
            placeholder="Enter Student Password" 
            onChange={(e)=> setStpassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <button
            onClick={Login} 
            className="login-btn">Login</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

so i have admin and company component too. so how do i setup routing these without changing the whole page is there any way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to have a login query param in the URL and according to that you can change the Component to be render.

URL: http://some-url?login=student

when Login query have Student you can show Student Login Component, this will help to use same page, just changing the Login Component based on the login query param, I have Created Demo for this which can help to understand more, let me know if you have any query

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ancient-field-dfsoe4?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx)

Comment: Does this solution help you? If yes can you mark the answer as accepted answer